# Multiple Selection field is blank in edit form, Select2 in edit form not triggering the selected values in edit form- Laravel Livewires

Tags: laravel, jquery-select2, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I have a select2 in a livewire component. Everything works fine but in my edit view, the selected options don't show in the box is selected. When I open the dropdown they show as highlighted, so data is coming from the backend. Please check below codes and output screenshots, Thanks in advance for your kind help.

### Livewire Component

```
public $home_categories = [];
public $no_of_products;

public function mount()
{
    $category = HomeCategory::all()->first();
    $this->home_categories = explode(',', $category->home_categories);
    $this->no_of_products = $category->no_of_products;
}
```

### Blade Component:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="home_categories" class="col-md-4 control-label">Choose Category</label>
<div class="col-md-6" wire:ignore>
    <select class="select2 form-control" name="home_categories[]" multiple="multiple" wire:model="home_categories">
        @foreach ($categories as $category)
            <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

### The script inside the livewire:

```
@push('scripts')
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.select2').select2();
        $('.select2').on('change', function (e) {
            var data = $('.select2').select2("val");
            @this.set('home_categories', data);
        });
    });
</script> @endpush
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use this code inside the blade components:

```
@if (in_array($category->id, $home_categories)) {{'selected'}} @endif
```

The script, component properties everything As-It-Is only changes in select option tag: like below code:

```
<select class="select2 form-control" name="home_categories[]" multiple="multiple" wire:model="home_categories">
@foreach ($categories as $category)
    <option value="{{$category->id}}" @if (in_array($category->id, $home_categories)){{'selected'}}
    @endif>{{$category->name}}</option>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

## In you component

public function hydrate(){$this->emit('data');}